# Using String format for doubles

Tags: java, string, format, double

Is it possible to format for example a **double** of value 0.41 to 00.41 using only String format ? In other words, is it possible to left zero pad **doubles** ? The result I would like should show as xx.xx

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find something simple although I am sure there is a simple solution... I have tried **%02.2f** but it doesn't work...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Change the `d` for `f` for floating point.

Comment: Why is my question marked as duplicate ? I am asking about doubles not integers... i know that it works for integers but I don't understand why it doesn't work for doubles...

Comment: Then show _how_ it doesn't work. Give us reproducible example.

Comment: If I use String.format("%02.2f", myDouble) and that myDouble = 0.41, it will print 0.41 and not 00.41

Comment: Please add that to your question. The number you provide after the `0` is the width. `0.41` already exceeds the width so no additional padding will be added.

Comment: [Here's the javadoc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: ok thanks so the result is %05.2f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public class DoubleFormat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float f =  0.41f;
        String s = Float.toString(f);

        System.out.println("0"+s); //Or
        System.out.printf("%05.2f\n", f);
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work with, for example, 14.01 which with your code would give 014.01. I would like two digits before the "." and two after.